# error: cannot find symbol class XYMultipleSeriesRenderer

Tags: achartengine

achartengine-1.0.0.jar is in the libs folder, marked to "Add as Library"

In org.chartengine/renderer is XYMultipleSeriesRenderer (not .java)

How can I tell it to bring in all this java code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to post the question. Of course I need to import the modules. Just because it's an incredible graphing package does not mean it's hard to use, or in my case not just like all the others.
sorry!